# How to terminate a thread after a window on this thread is closed in WPF c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading. I am doing a project using wpf.

Brief introduction to my project:

1. One mainwindow
2. One method in mainwindow creates another thread that creates another window, which is called window 2.
3. Whenever window 2 is visible, mainwindow is suspended(so i used `join()` method to suspend the main thread)

The problem is whenever I closed the window 2, the new thread doesn't terminate. so the main thread is forever suspended. So how to solve this problem.

The following code is where i create a new thread for window 2 in MainWindow Class:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread addThread = new Thread(CreateCourseWindow);
        addThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        addThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        addThread.Join();
        if (addcourse.Saved) CreateCourseButton(myCourses.Count(), myCourses.Last());
    }
```

The following code is the entry function for the new thread

```
private void CreateCourseWindow()
    {
        addcourse = new AddCourse();
        addcourse.Activate();
        addcourse.Show();
        addcourse.Topmost = true;
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

The following code is where i want to terminate the thread

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

AddCourse is the window 2 class.

Comment: Can we have some more information please? Why are you using the threads in this manner? What is this attempting to achieve?

Comment: Because I want to suspend (means User can't interact with) the MainWindow whenever I have the window 2 on the front.

Comment: I see, that's fine but as your accepted answer states you don't need threads or anything like that, you can always change the Window's `IsHitTestVisible` to False so the user can't click anything on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't create multiple UI threads.  It creates a real mess that's *very* hard to deal with.  Only ever have on UI thread in your application unless you're *sure* that you need more, and that you really know what you're doing.

As for this specific case, you don't need to worry about asynchrony, multiple threads, or any of it:

```
ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow();
this.Hide();
child.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

By using `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` you remove all the pesky asynchrony issues.

If you want the parent window visible but not enabled you can remove the show/hide but leave the `ShowDialog`, which will ensure the parent is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I want to show the mainwindow and the window 2 at the same time and just simply suspend the mainwindow while window 2 is active, what should I do?

Comment: @user1998777 YOu should do what I mentioned in my last sentence and just remove the show/hide calls.

Comment: And I not only want to disable the parent window, I also want the parent window wait for the data from the child window and do some execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not advised to suspend a window by hanging the thread. What you get is a complete non-responsive window, that doesn't handle any Windows event at all. For example, it will not react to move events, or set cursor events, or other things that you would expect even a disabled window to have. Furthermore, if there are any COM STA objects on this thread they will hang (and sometimes there can be such object even if you didn't explicitly create them).
2. How are you opening the window from the second thread? It sounds like this thread is running a loop which doesn't terminate when the window is closed. If you post some code it can help.